# Call to i:im() in application debugger failed in ejabberd

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I'm trying to debug ejabberd. I have compiled the files with debug_info. I start ejabberd, then use ejabberd debug to get into the shell. Once in there, running im() produces "Call to i:im() in application debugger failed". I can't figure out what's causing this. Any ideas on how to debug?

Edit

I've tried running this in just the erl shell independent of ejabberd and it still fails. So it looks like it's related to my erlang setup as opposed to a problem with my ejabberd setup.

Comment: Can you paste the error you are getting ?

Comment: Unfortunately all I get is "call to i:im() in application debugger failed." I have the log level turned all the way up, but there's nothing in the logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foolish me: apt-get install erlang-debugger solved the problem.